# Use AsyncTask Except Downloading

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Wherever I've seen use of **asynctask** , it is used for **downloading** or operation that returns some results. But What if i just want to set a time to time updation of my TextView in activity and do some work at the end .

But at the same time How can i **cancel** asynctask operation from activity so its **onPostExecute** , do not run .Like when back button is pressed from activity. Any clues ?

### [UPDATE]

For Time to time updation i mean:

```
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.disco);
try{
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
       Thread.sleep();
       tv.setText(" "+i);
    }
}
catch(Exception e){}
/* i know i can achieve finally in onPostExecute but what if i want to cancel it during runtime*/
finally{
   // do some more operations after execution
}
```

Comment: For time to time updation use Handlers. Call Async task in your Handaler if needed.

Comment: @AnandSingh i've given some chunk to further explain my problem .

Comment: you can cancel `handler` postDelayed call anytime for that just write `myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable)`

Comment: it worth a shot , let me try it and notify again

Comment: @AnandSingh i cannot loop through handler , again and again to give me delayed results , well the problem still persists :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done it myself after some brain storming and searching , i am using CountDownTimer.

in **OnCreate()**:

```
    counter = new CountDownTimer((PROGRESSSECONDS+1)*1000,1000) {
        int collapsed = 0;
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            collapsed++;
            pb.setProgress(collapsed);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Intent in = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,PointsDrawerActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    };
    counter.start();
```

in **onBackPressed()**:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    counter.cancel();
    counter = null;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
}
```

it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should use timer task rather than Async task here.

Here is sample:

```
private TimerTask timerTask;
int i = 0;
 timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //Do your text view update here.
                        tv.setText(" "+ (i++));
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

In your onResume() do like:

```
private Timer timer;
public void onResume() {
   timer = new Timer();
   timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000); // time in milliseconds, you can set accordingly requirement.
}
```

And onPause() you can stop it by:

```
public void onPause() {
if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
}
```

Comment: it seems to be good approach can you please explain , TimeTask with respect to my specific given problem code?

Comment: Just updated code above, so you can just copy paste it in your activity and you are ready to go.

Comment: i think we are forgetting about finally clause ! and you cant update value of `i` in `tv.setText(" "+ (i++));` , unless it is final or variable within runnable.

Comment: When you call onPause() you should stop timer and do needful over there which you are asking in part of finally.

Comment: No ! , basically loops runs `n` times suppose 3 , so each time `tv` has to be updated but after wait of 1 sec and after `n` seconds have collapsed finally clause should run , but finally should not run if i press `back button` in activity.

Comment: In that case, you can do using i count, as if you want to do textview update at every 1 sec and after 120 sec, you need to do finally execute, you can do like if(i < 120) .. update text view else execute finally block and also timer.cancel() so no more execution.

Answer (score 0):

`Handler` is optimum for your requirement

```
handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            callMethod();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

and in order to cancel an ongoing `AsyncTask` the official docs says it all

> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean).
>   Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to
>   return true.
>
> ```
> After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[])
> ```
>
> returns.
>
> ```
> To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically
> ```
>
> from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for
>   instance.)

Ex: `MyTask.cancel(true);`

Comment: it is rather difficult to periodically check on my each iteration that task was canceled or not and inefficient , but thanks for your effort.